# Issue occuring in installing AgoraProctorUI in Xcode 15.1

Tags: ios

[!] Error installing AgoraProctorUI
[!] /usr/bin/git clone git@github.com:AgoraIO-Community/proctor-ios.git /var/folders/hv/cwfj99vx16sb0l9z2_4zr3880000gn/T/d20240222-63153-1yxxj7u --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch AgoraProctorUI_v1.0.0
Cloning into '/var/folders/hv/cwfj99vx16sb0l9z2_4zr3880000gn/T/d20240222-63153-1yxxj7u'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

pod 'AgoraClassroomSDK_iOS'
pod 'AgoraEduUI'
pod 'AgoraWidgets'
pod 'AgoraProctorSDK'
pod 'AgoraProctorUI'

i just removed pod,

#pod 'AgoraClassroomSDK_iOS'
#pod 'AgoraEduUI'
#pod 'AgoraWidgets'
#pod 'AgoraProctorSDK'
#pod 'AgoraProctorUI'

but still Agora library is not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.